# Сложность алгоритмов

Tags: алгоритм, асимптотика

Не понимаю, что такое асимптотика сложности алгоритмов, объясните. Например: O(n), O(n^2), O(log n), O(nlog n), o(n), o(n^2), o(log n), o(nlog n).

Comment: Примеры? В книжках. Например:
Ахо и др. Построение и анализ вычислительных алгоритмов.
Рейнгольд Комбинаторные алгоритмы. Теория и практика.
У Кнута в Искусстве программирования. И ещё много где.

Comment: Вы сами-то разбирались? Чего непонятно? Что Вы смотрели, что изучали?