# Что означает O(n^{2}). в описании сложности алгоритма?

Tags: алгоритм, любой-язык, асимптотика

Что означает O(n<sup>2</sup>) в описании сложности алгоритма?

Что значит О, что значит n?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/487278/6104996  .... там кстати график наглядный

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, а у нас перевода не было?

Comment: @Qwertiy я не нашел. всё что я нашел примерное - это убитый старый вопрос https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/64837/191482  от 11-го года

Comment: мне сделать ответ общим? Дописали бы. Если кто-то представляет что стоит писать)

Comment: @pavel если возьмете на себя труд перевода, то репа ваша :).

Comment: @andreycha дело не  в переводе, это достаточно сложный вопрос, который обычно на опыте понимают) я не знаю как это описать лучше, в ответе на SO мне тоже не особо нравится.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/295121/%D0%92%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%8B-%D0%BE%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8-%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B2 линк

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/685066/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%be%d1%86%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b2%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%8f-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d1%8b-%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b3%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%bc%d0%b0-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%bd%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b8-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-n ещё 1 линк

Answer (score 15, accepted):

O - ничего не означает. Просто буква :) Вообще это из теории эквивалентных функций [image: https://habrastorage.org/getpro/habr/post_images/fd0/c1c/9ed/fd0c1c9ed7d949c2cd258b45302016ca.png]

n - параметр размерности входных данных (обычно из контекста понятно о чём речь, пример: размер массива). Или иной параметр, от значения которого зависит время работы.

Теперь о вопросе что это значит в сумме, это значит что с ростом объёма входных данных в 10 раз, ваша функция будет работать не более чем в 100 раз дольше. Учтите, оценки асимптотические, работают при больших n. Поэтому иногда квадрат быстрее чем линия из-за скрытых констант.

Зачем это надо. Вот например классическая таблица с оценками алгоритмов. Используя её мы можем принять решение какую структуру данных использовать под наш конкретный профиль нагрузки.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Следует помнить, что нотация обычно амортизирована и не всегда показывает время на 1 операцию. Пример - любой динамический массив вроде как и O(1) добавить, но регулярно он может быть полностью скопирован (максимальное время единичной операции растёт, и это не противоречит О - нотации).

Наглядный пример роста числа операций от О-нотации

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При этом при О - нотации принято **не** указывать константы. Т.е. O(n) == O(2*n), так же все младшие степени "поглощаются" старшими O(n<sup>2</sup> + n) == O(n<sup>2</sup>). Исключение может быть только при смешивании полиномиальной и экспоненциальной части (для малых n полином может быть больше).

Ссылки:

- [английский связанный ответ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/487278/6104996)
- [цикл статей о О нотации, хабр](https://habrahabr.ru/post/196226/)
- [примеры сложностей алгоритмов, хабр](https://habrahabr.ru/post/188010/)

Comment: и вот тут , можно весь цикл посмотреть , https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DN28rNAkd44&list=PLwwk4BHih4fjIT5cT4i1s93b99aJScUGB&index=5